# Is there a way to create a batch job in dataflow which reads from a pubsub topic?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a dataflow pipeline in streaming mode as it reads from a pubsub topic. I wish to modify it to batch mode. I need so inorder to use FlexRS as it is supported only for batch mode.
Beam version : 2.13.0

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using BoundedReadFromUnbounded source that allows to convert unbounded collection to bounded.

```
UnboundedSource<String> unboundedSource  = ...;
PCollection<String> boundedCollection=
     p.apply(Read.from(unboundedSource).withMaxNumRecords(10));
```

You can also utilize [withMaxReadTime](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Read.Unbounded.html#withMaxReadTime-org.joda.time.Duration-)